# Harmonic function with mean value property related to proof of Schwarz's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

When I tried to prove the Schwarz integral formula I found a sketch [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671681/proof-of-schwarz-formula), where I confused by the formula

$$u(z)=\text{Re} \int_0^{2\pi} u(e^{i\theta })\frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{2\pi}$$

I tried to prove this using the mean value property of harmonic function

$$u(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} u(z_0+re^{i\theta})\mathrm{d}\theta $$

But I can't see where to go from this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'd say for $|z| = r$ : $u(z) = \lim_{a \to 1^-}Re\int_0^{2\pi} u(re^{i\theta })\frac{e^{i\theta}+az}{e^{i\theta}-az} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{2\pi}$ is the Fourier series theorem, and it stays true for $|z| < r$ by "harmonic continuation"